# "TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable", why am I getting this error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium. webdriver. chrome. options import Options

web = 'https://www.amazon.com'
driver_path = 'V:\Python Project\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

s=Service('V:\Python Project\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get(web)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
keyword = "Table"

search = driver.find_element(By.ID,"twotabsearchtextbox")
search.send_keys(keyword)
# click search button
search_button = driver.find_element(By.ID,'nav-search-submit-button')
search_button.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

product_asin = []
product_name = []
product_price = []
product_ratings = []
product_ratings_num = []
product_link = []

items =(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "s-result-item sasin"))) *=>Error on this line*

for item in items:
    # find name
    name = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal")
    product_name.append(name.text)

    # find ASIN number
    data_asin = item.get_attribute("data-asin")
    product_asin.append(data_asin)

    # find price
    whole_price = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-price-whole")
    fraction_price = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-price-fraction")

    if whole_price != [] and fraction_price != []:
        price = '.'.join([whole_price[0].text, fraction_price[0].text])
    else:
        price = 0
    product_price.append(price)

    # find ratings box
    ratings_box = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-row a-size-small")

    # find ratings and ratings_num
    if ratings_box != []:
        ratings = ratings_box[0].get_attribute('aria-label')
        ratings_num = ratings_box[1].get_attribute('aria-label')
    else:
        ratings, ratings_num = 0, 0

    product_ratings.append(ratings)
    product_ratings_num.append(str(ratings_num))

    # find link
    link = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a-link-normal a-text-normal").get_attribute("href")
    product_link.append(link)

driver.quit()

# to check data scraped
print(product_name)
print(product_asin)
print(product_price)
print(product_ratings)
print(product_ratings_num)
print(product_link)
```

For the code above I am getting the following error:

```
for item in items:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

I am working on the above code, but it is giving me the error, "TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable". It should be working fine, as it is mostly correct, but don't know what is missing, which gives the error. Please can anyone provide mw with the solution?.

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html the items = is not locating any of the elements instead use `items.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "s-result-item sasin")` which will produce an iterable

Answer (score 0):

```
EC.presence_of_all_elements_located
```

this function will not return anything it will only check is the item which you want is available or not. Use something like below

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "s-result-item sasin")))

    rows = self.browser.find_elements(
        By.CLASS_NAME, "s-result-item sasin")

    self.assertIn(
        rowItem,
        [row.text for row in rows]
    )
```

I think there is some mistake in class can you check below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium. webdriver. chrome. options import Options

web = 'https://www.amazon.com'
driver_path = 'chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

# ser=Service(executable_path='chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

driver.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get(web)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
keyword = "Table"

search = driver.find_element(By.ID,"twotabsearchtextbox")
search.send_keys(keyword)
# click search button
search_button = driver.find_element(By.ID,'nav-search-submit-button')
search_button.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

product_asin = []
product_name = []
product_price = []
product_ratings = []
product_ratings_num = []
product_link = []

EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "s-result-item"))

rows = driver.find_elements(
        By.CLASS_NAME, "s-result-item")

print(rows)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing the solution. But whenever I add 'Wait' in the code, it returns, "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:", this error.

Comment: Not quite. The function returns a function used by the wait logic to wait until some element appears in the DOM. That happens when some javascript decides to add the element to the DOM. Or , it doesn't do it in a timeout period, so you get the error.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Alright, will update if the issue is resolved. But for now, still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: can you share what issue are you facing ?

Comment: I have updated the code check it, it is working in mine